# How can i check the pattern of data set is similar

Tags: python, compare, similarity

I am using python and i would like to check is the pattern of a group of data set compare with one specific data-set is similar, e.g.

```
[1,11,21,31,41]
```

is similar to

```
[1,10,24,32,44]
```

and i would like to set some threshold to identify is that similar, for example i would like to set the similarity percentage at 90%.

Please help, i have stuck at this programming for a week

Comment: How do you define similarity in your question ?

Comment: 90% of what? You should define your idea of similarity, and then you can program it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SpghttCd my definition of similarity is that their pattern looks the same, for example [1,5,10,15,20] is similar to [5,11,14,19,27], but it is not similar to [5,1,8,3,27].

i have tried to use sklearn.neighbors to find the nearest neighbor, however it seems not working

Comment: I know what you mean in this basic way, but this is not a definition of similarity in a calculable, measurable way, it's just a vague verbal description, which might hint persons with mathematical background to what you mean. What you need is either a clear definition of how your requested similarity property of a pair of arrays can be _calculated_ in terms of "percent" (besides the trivial solution, that two times the same array will lead to "100%")  - or a library, which does it for you because others already created this similarity measure algorithm. In other words: why 90% in your example?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: def is_similar(a, b, percent=90/100):
   ...:     if len(a) != len(b):
   ...:         return False
   ...:     for i, j in zip(a, b):
   ...:         if 1 - abs(i-j)/i < percent:
   ...:             return False
   ...:     return True
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: is_similar([1,11,21,31,41], [1,10,24,32,44])
Out[2]: False

In [3]: is_similar([1,11,21,31,41], [1,10,23,32,44])
Out[3]: True
```

Comment: `1 - abs(i-j)/i` Why `i` and not `j`? What if `i=90` and `j=100`? One would pass the test and the other would not. Maybe use `min`, `max`, or `avg` of `i` and `j` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
data1=[1,11,21,31,41]
data2=[1,10,24,32,44]    
totalDif = 0

for (int i=0; i<len(data1); i++):
    difference = abs(data1[i] - data2[i])
    totalDif += difference
```

Now you can use the value of **totalDif** to define a certain percentage. For example if **totalDif** is **0** it means that the similarity is 100%. The higher **totalDif**, the less similarity.